# using pseudo :after-element to create a triangle shape color overlay

Tags: css

I am trying to create a shape color overlay with pure CSS like the [image]

However, I can't quite figure out how to create the triangle. I would assume I have to use CSS pseudo `:after` element. However, none of the solutions I have tried so far seems to work and is not responsive at all.

How do I recreate a shape color overlay as shown in the image? Thanks in advance!

**My code:**

```
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .bg-img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-blend-mode: multiply;
      background-color: initial;
      background-image: url("http://unsplash.it/1200x800"), linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(43,135,218,0) 50%,rgba(41,196,169,0.61) 50%);
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

[Code Snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/sojgby5k/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider a multiple background layer to achieve this:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-img {
  height: 100%;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background: 
    url("http://unsplash.it/1200x800") center/cover, 
   linear-gradient(rgba(41, 196, 169, 0.61),rgba(41, 196, 169, 0.61)) right/50% 100%,
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,rgba(41, 196, 169, 0.61) 50%) calc(50% - 50px) 0/100px 50.05%,
   linear-gradient(to top right,   transparent 49.8%,rgba(41, 196, 169, 0.61) 50%) calc(50% - 50px) 100%/100px 50.05%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img"></div>
```

Here is another idea considering skew and pseudo element:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-img {
  height: 100%;
  background: 
    url("http://unsplash.it/1200x800") center/cover no-repeat;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.bg-img:before,
.bg-img:after{
  content:"";
  z-index:0;
  position:absolute;
  background:rgba(41, 196, 169, 0.61);
  width:calc(50% + 100px);
  height:50%;
  right:0;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.bg-img:before {
  top:0;
  transform:skewX(-35deg);
  transform-origin:bottom right;
}
.bg-img:after {
  bottom:0;
  transform:skewX(35deg);
  transform-origin:top right;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.bg-img { width: 100%; height: 400px; background-image: url("http://unsplash.it/1200x800"); background-size: cover; position: relative; }
.bg-img:before { content: ''; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: auto; left: 50%; border: 200px solid rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.40); border-left: 0; border-top-color: transparent; border-bottom-color: transparent; margin-left: -200px; }
.bg-img:after { content: ''; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 50%; background-color: rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.40); }
```

Please check this will work.